# MySQL if value is null then don't search

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT nfc_film.title, nfc_film.film_id, nfc_film.description, nfc_film.release_year, nfc_film.rating, nfc_film.last_update, nfc_category.name 
  FROM nfc_film
  JOIN nfc_film_category
    ON nfc_film.film_id = nfc_film_category.film_id
  JOIN nfc_category
    ON nfc_film_category.category_id = nfc_film_category.category_id
 WHERE
       nfc_film.title LIKE :searchterm
   AND
       nfc_category.name = :category
 LIMIT 10
OFFSET :page
```

I'm aware of the IFNULL() function. But say if :category was either empty or null, how would i just make the query as if that condition wasn't in there.

So like `If :category is null then don't search in nfc_category.name`

Answer (score 0):

You can just change your `WHERE` conditions to include empty/null tests for `category`. If it is empty or `NULL`, the result of the `nfc_category.name = :category` will be irrelevant (and should be optimised away). Note the need for parentheses to avoid operator precedence issues.

```
(:category = '' OR :category IS NULL OR nfc_category.name = :category)
```

Dependent on your [`PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) setting, you may need to use another parameter name e.g. `:category0`, `:category1` for the second and third usage of the parameter.

Comment: @AdamCole Did this answer your question? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?